# Serverlocation moved and how can I Move the files

Tags: ssh, web-server, ftp

I´ve a big problem.
I have to move data from an old Webspace which is only accessibla by ftp.

No we have a new root server which is accessible by ssh of course :-)

No i Need to move all data from the old space but there is a lot of Gb of files.
Is there a way to fetch all files directly from the old ftp to the storage and not over a third station (my local machine)?

I´ve tried it with ftp but without success.

I think I´ve used the wrong commands.

Is there a way to etablish something like this including all files and directorys?

Thank you in advance

Bernhard

Answer (score 1):

- [lftp](http://lftp.yar.ru/)

Lftp is able to mirror a remote directory to local, or the opposite:

> lftp  has builtin mirror which can download or update a whole directory
>          tree. There is also reverse mirror (mirror -R) which uploads or updates
>          a  directory  tree  on  server. Mirror can also synchronize directories
>          between two remote servers, using FXP if available.

So you just have to install it on your new server, and using it like this:

```
# lftp ftp://user:pass@server -e "mirror -e /html /var/www/site ; quit"
```

/html is the remote path, /var/www/site your local. The syntax is very script-friendly, so if you have to schedule this over time, a cron job will do the job !

- [FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol)

FXP is like ftp from one server to another, but transfer orders are given from a remote client. And most fxp-capable clients are also able to do SCP, so it *should* be possible to FXP between the ftp server and the new server, running ssh.